# What was the significance of the hummingbird in the movie Cowboys & Aliens(2011)?

Tags: cowboys-and-aliens-2011

While watching [Cowboys & Aliens(2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409847/) in a couple of scenes there was a hummingbird.  It was not clear if it was actually present or if it was only in Jake's mind.  I watched all the bonus material on the DVD and did not see any reference to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hummingbird was a [CGI](http://www.artofvfx.com/?p=1632) creation. According to the [Director's Audio Commentary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboys_&_Aliens#cite_ref-commentary9_49-0), the hummingbird is intended to portray a;

> "**good spirit**" that could represent either Alice or Ella

In the [novelisation of the film](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10904100-cowboys-and-aliens), the final appearance of the hummingbird is explicitly stated to represent the end of his journey;

> He raised his head again, to see the hummingbird flying off into the
>   distance, vanishing almost before his eyes could see which way it
>   went...realizing that he truly was free to choose his own path, at
>   last.

[image: Hummingbird Cowboys and Aliens]